# ggplot2 add geologic time axis annotation: filled rects with names between axis and data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add geologic time scale (GTS) information to the age axis of geological data using ggplot2. An example of the GTS next to data can be seen in [this image](http://publications.iodp.org/preliminary_report/318/images/318_F25.gif).
I was already able to create this [in base graphics](https://github.com/japhir/stratPlot/blob/master/StratPlot.R#L834), but I want to make it using ggplot2.

Here's what I was able to do so far:

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

# some fake data
dat <- data.frame(age = 41:50, abundance = rnorm(10, 5, 3),
```

geologic time scale, meticulously—and thus not fully—copied from https://engineering.purdue.edu/Stratigraphy/charts/rgb.html

```
GTS <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/japhir/stratPlot/master/GTS_colours.csv") %>%
  mutate(col = rgb(R, G, B, maxColorValue = 255)) %>%
  mutate(mean = (end - start) / 2 + start)
```

Plot it all:

```
p <- dat %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = age, y = abundance)) 

p + GTS %>% subset(type == "Age") %>%
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = -Inf, ymax = -5, fill = col), 
            inherit.aes = FALSE, data = .) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  GTS %>% subset(type == "Age") %>%
    geom_text(aes(x = mean, y = -Inf, label = name), 
              inherit.aes = FALSE, data = ., 
              angle = 90, hjust = 0, check_overlap = TRUE)
```

Here are the problems I encountered:

- `ymax` should be a value between 0 and 1, scaled up to that fraction of the already existing plot. I noticed that `theme(legend.position = ...)` already does this, so I should be able to steal some code from there. In base graphics I did this by calling `par("usr")` to get the plot limits, and then scaling it between those.
- Currently, I'm only plotting the "Age" information. It should also be possible to add other types from the GTS next to each other—like [this plot](https://www.mun.ca/biology/scarr/139413_Extinction.jpg).
- It should behave like an annotation, not changing the xlim of the plot. But it seems like `annotate()` cannot take an aesthetic mapping to data.
- Ultimately, I want to apply the same method to map raster images of core photographs next to the axis—like [this image](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alejandro_Cearreta/publication/318497107/figure/fig10/AS:533689642569730@1504252934743/Fig-212-Core-photograph-Al-normalized-Pb-distribution-and-excess-210-Pb-and-137-Cs.ppm).
- It should be possible to `coord_flip()`, such that the `geom_text` direction also updates.
- Adding a `facet_grid` should not duplicate the annotation on each plot if the common axis is the age axis.

Maybe these should all be separate questions, but they are quite integrated and I thought I should give it a try like this first :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes use of grobs, since I couldn't think of any hack within ggplot that works without repetition in individual facet plots...

**Step 0: Create a complete ggplot.** This should include all the geoms, coordinate transformations, themes, etc:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)

set.seed(333)
dat <- data.frame(age = 41:50, abundance = rnorm(10, 5, 3))

dat <- rbind(dat %>% mutate(f = "a"),
              dat %>% mutate(f = "b", abundance = (abundance + rnorm(10)) * 0.5))

p <- ggplot(dat,
            aes(x = age, y = abundance)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +     # move normal time axis to the right
  facet_grid(~f, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  coord_flip()
p
```

[image: step 0]

**Step 1: Convert to grob.** Note the cells that correspond to the left axis (where we'll place the geologic time axis), as well as the plot panels.

```
pg <- ggplotGrob(p)

j.axis <- unique(gtable::gtable_filter(pg, "axis-l", trim = FALSE)$layout$l)
j.plot <- unique(gtable::gtable_filter(pg, "panel", trim = FALSE)$layout$l) 
i.axis <- unique(gtable::gtable_filter(pg, "axis-l", trim = FALSE)$layout$t)
```

**Step 2: Define the relative width for the geologic time axis.** I used 20% in this example:

```
pg$widths[j.axis] <- 0.2 * sum(pg$widths[j.plot])
```

**Step 3: filter GTS for the relevant age range, & calculate relative heights**:

```
x.range <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.range
y.range <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.range

filter.GTS <- GTS %>% 
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("Eon", "Era", "Period", "Epoch", "Age"))) %>%

  # optional: plot only subset of bar types
  filter(type %in% c("Eon", "Era", "Period", "Epoch", "Age")) %>%

  filter(end >= min(y.range),
         start <= max(y.range)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(start = max(start, min(y.range)),
         end = min(end, max(y.range))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(height = (end - start) / (max(end) - min(start))) %>%

  # optional: suppress names for short bars (e.g. Bartonian Age)
  # if bar height < 10% of plot height
  mutate(name = ifelse(height <= 0.1, "", name)) %>%

  select(name, type, col, height) %>%
  arrange(type)

> filter.GTS
# A tibble: 7 x 4
         name   type     col     height
        <chr> <fctr>   <chr>      <dbl>
1 Phanerozoic    Eon #9AD9DD 1.00000000
2    Cenozoic    Era #F2F91D 1.00000000
3   Paleogene Period #FD9A52 1.00000000
4      Eocene  Epoch #FDB46C 1.00000000
5                Age #FDC091 0.06565657
6    Lutetian    Age #FCB482 0.66666667
7    Ypresian    Age #FCA773 0.26767677
```

**Step 4: Create table to hold geologic times**.

```
unique.types <- unique(filter.GTS$type) %>% as.character()

# create empty gtable
gt <- gtable(widths = rep(unit(1, "null"), 
                          times = length(unique.types)),
             heights = unit(1, "null"))

# fill gtable with individual table grobs for each type of geologic time
for(i in seq_along(unique.types)){

  period.df <- filter(filter.GTS, type == unique.types[i])

  tt <- tableGrob(d = select(period.df, name),
                  cols = NULL, rows = NULL,
                  heights = unit(period.df$height, "null"),
                  widths = unit(1, "null"),
                  theme = ttheme_minimal(
                    core = list(bg_params = list(fill = period.df$col,
                                                 col = "white"),
                                fg_params = list(rot = 90))
                  ))

  gt <- gtable_add_grob(x = gt,
                        grobs = tt,
                        t = 1, l = i)

}

# check result
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image: step 4]

**Step 5: Combine table with plot**.

```
for(i in i.axis){
  pg <- gtable_add_grob(x = pg,
                        grobs = gt,
                        t = i,
                        l = j.axis)
}

grid.draw(pg)
```

[image: step 5]

The above should work with facets that go in the other direction as well:

```
p <- ggplot(dat,
            aes(x = age, y = abundance)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
  facet_grid(f~., scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  coord_flip()

# same steps as above

grid.draw(pg)
```

[image: alternative]

Comment: This is really great, I'll be digging into it in the weekend. Ultimately, it would be very nice to add this to a ggplot with something like `+ geom_gts()` or `+ annotate_gts()` with some parameters, do you think that is feasible?

Comment: @Japhir Based on my understanding of how ggplot works, I don't think so as long as you have the facet requirement (which means the geologic time is part of the axis rather than the plot panel). But I'll be glad to hear if anyone else has different insights into this.